# REST API different resources for GET and POST/PUT?

Tags: c#, rest, resources, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently in the process of designing as RESTful of an API as I can using Microsoft's Web API 2 in C#. What I'm struggling on is how best to represent resources or the proper way to do it where the GET call and POST/PUT are very different.

For example say I have something calls states that have an id, name, status, etc., these can be assigned to a document. So I have a route like this /documents/{id}/states/ . If I call a GET here I need to get the full list of all assigned states including their id, name, etc.

However, in order to change which states are assigned to the document I simply need to pass the id. I cannot do this individually, it must be an array that gets sent up since users may be interacting with hundreds or thousands at a time.

So in this case I have a few issues. I don't even know if POST or PUT is correct here, and second whichever one it is can I just take in an array of integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would suggest PUT is the method you would be wanting to use, as you know the location of the resource that you are updating. For more info, see here: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/

In ASP.NET Web API 2 you can use the [FromBody] parameter attribute, so that your method signature would be:
`public void UpdateStates(int id, [FromBody]List<int> states) {}`
More info on parameter attributes can be found here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api